# Importing behave library in executable created with PyInstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, python-behave

I am using PyInstaller to create a single-file executable.

The script is executing behave tests, within a subprocess routine.

Sample:

```
cmd = ['behave']

proc = subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Currently this requires behave to be installed on the machine, prior of executable to be executed.

Is there a way behave library can be bundled into the executable?
I've been looking into hidden imports, but with no success.
Maybe a better idea sounds to be runtime hooks? I welcome any inputs.